# Nexus 5 weird charging behaviour

Tags: battery, nexus-5, battery-life

I've had my Nexus 5 for about a year and a half now, but lately it's showing weird charging behaviour (check battery history graph):

[image: Nexus 5 battery history]

I leave it charging every night and it's supposed to reach 100%, now it doesn't even go beyond 48%. What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what do you mean by "weird charging behaviour"? All I see is, when charging, the mobile network signal and WiFi were turned off. Did you mean the charging power seems to be weaker?

Comment: @AndrewT. Sorry, edited question to make it more clear.

Comment: Based on your chart, the phone takes around 2h to reach 48% from what looks like 15%. This is considered rather slow generally. Are you using the official Nexus 5 charger?

Comment: @Huey yes I'm using the cable and charger that came with the phone, plugged into a wall socket.

Comment: Examine the connection. It's possible the connection isn't as secure as it used to be and the phone occasionally becomes disconnected. Also, try borrowing a charger (the socket as well as the cable) from someone that's rated 2A and see if that changes things.

Comment: There are 3 (or more) possible causes: the voltage source, the USB power adapter, or the USB cable itself. It happened to me when using multi-plug extension with USB input, turned out it "stopped" charging after a while (icon shows charging, but battery wasn't charged). OTOH, using the same cable plugged to a laptop on the same power source, I got it charged to 100%. I haven't concluded if the multi-plug is problematic, but anyway I solved my issue. So try different combination to pinpoint the cause.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just decided to let the battery drop down to about 3%, restart the phone and then charge. Now it's fine again!